# Determining the number of squares in a modified square

Tags: java, algorithm

I am creating a matchstick game, which can be played [here](http://www.sheppardsoftware.com/braingames/matchsticks/matchsticks.htm) if you don't know what that is.  However, I need to check if a given board is a winning board, so I need to count the number of squares left on the board.  For example, I could have the board:

```
(Graphical representation)         (Matrix representation)
     ---   ---   ---                   0 1 0 1 0 1 0
    |          |     |                 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
                 ---                   0 0 0 0 0 1 0
    |          |     |                 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
     ---   ---   ---                   0 1 0 1 0 1 0
    |    |     |     |                 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
     ---   ---   ---                   0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

which has 7 squares.  However, I have no idea how I could determine the number of squares here.  Each `---` or `|` represents a matchstick, and a zero in the matrix represents the absence of a matchstick, while a 1 represents the presence of one.  Any help is appreciated, because I have no idea how to figure it out.

Comment: Hint: 1s on even rows (if you start to count at 0) represent horizontal matchsticks and 1s at odd rows represent vertical ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is only to count the number of squares and the board is 9x9:
There are only 3 type of squares possible:

```
010   01010  0101010
101   10001  1000001
010   00000  0000000
      10001  1000001
      01010  0000000
             0101010
```

By matching these patterns in your board you would be able to count the number of squares.

An idea would be to see the matrix as a string of 49 char in which you look for patterns.
For example (for the small squares) you take groups of 17 char and compare with 010xxxx101xxxx010 which could be written as a regexp `/010[0-1]{4}101[0-1]{4}010/`

Comment: This works, thank you.  I am very new to reg-exes, so could you help me with the regex for the other 2 as well?